# Distinct like String Manipulation

Tags: string, flutter

I working on Flutter project. I have query regarding string manipulation. I storing some value like following

```
String a="31,31,31,31,31,31,31,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53"
```

I have output like Distinct in query

```
a="31,41,53"
```

may I know how to achieve this function.

Thanks in advance
Sathish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void main() {
  String a =
      "31,31,31,31,31,31,31,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53";
  var values = a.split(',');
  var result = Set.from(values).join(',');
  print(result);
}
```

Result:

`31,41,53`